# jQuery disable checkbox style action

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to disable an action that styles checkboxes and radiobuttons but i don't know how i can do this.

**I have this Javascript line:**

```
$("input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]").customInput();
```

This is working great, but when a checkbox is inside a table i want to disable that action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I have not attempted to run it but the idea is solid.

```
$("input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]").each (function () 
{ 
if ($(this).parent("table").length == 0) 
{
customInput();
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Vinnyq12, i didn't work... i get this error: `error Uncaught ReferenceError: customInput is not defined`

Comment: Hi @Sarah, now i get no error... but still the costumInput loads in tables

Answer (score 1):

Use **parents**() instead of parent().

You could also try the filter function;

```
$("input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]").filter(function(){ return $(this).parents("table").length }).customInput();​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thnx! the parents did the job. Your filter function didn't work for me.